# What is this array?

Tags: java, arrays

I come across this code line in a book and it said this is legal , but I don't really understand though having googling.
the code is:

```
Boolean [] ba [];
```

I just know that to create an array, it should be like this:

```
int [] numberArray;

int numberArray [];

int [] [] num2DArray;
```

Thanks!

Comment: It depends on what programming language you're talking about...

Comment: From a few indices, and from OP's other questions, it's probably Java.

Comment: BTW a Boolean[] is very inefficient. It uses 32-bits per actual bit. A BitSet is likely to be a better choice.

Comment: Your example will make sense in this line of code: `Boolean[] ba, ba2[];`. The `ba` and `ba2` has different types although declared on the same line.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All those 3 declarations have the same meaning in java :

```
Boolean  [][] ba ;
Boolean  [] ba [];
Boolean  ba [][] ;
```

I don't really like it but as there aren't any confusion possible, there is no very big harm in letting them be equivalent. The rationale was that C and C++ coders were used to a certain notation :

```
 int a[];
```

while the recommendation in java is to consistently declare the type before as in

```
 int[] a;
```

Here's the reference : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.2

And two extracts :

> Brackets are allowed in declarators as a nod to the tradition of C and
>   C++. The general rules for variable declaration, however, permit
>   brackets to appear on both the type and in declarators, so that the
>   local variable declaration
>
> [...]
>
> We do not recommend "mixed notation" in an array variable declaration,
>   where brackets appear on both the type and in declarators.

In order to be more readable in Java, I suggest you stick to the usual

```
 Boolean[][] ba ;
```

Note that you have a similar behavior for method declarations. Here's an excerpt from the `ByteArrayOutputStream` class source code:

```
public synchronized byte toByteArray()[] {
    return Arrays.copyOf(buf, count);
}
```

This is allowed [for compatibility](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4) but please don't use that. Most coders at first sight wouldn't notice the `[]` and thus wouldn't immediately read that this method returns an array.

Comment: Thank dystroy and everybody! I see now!

Answer (score 4):

```
Boolean [] ba [];
```

It is a two dimensional array.

For array declaration you can put bracket before or after your variable name.

```
int ba[]; or int ba [];
```

And both are same. For 2-d or two dimensional array

```
int [] [] num2DArray;
int [] num2DArray []; 
int num2DArray[] [];
```

This all are same. But It is recommended that

*String[] is preferred because it keeps the type of args — array of String — all together. In a more complicated and poorly formatted method signature, it could be easy to miss a [] after a parameter name.*

Answer (score 3):

one dimensional and two dimensional array can be declare  in different ways.

```
int arr [];
int [] arr;
```

Two dimensional array:

```
String [][] myStringArray = new String [x][y];
Boolean  [][] booeanArr ;
Boolean  [] booeanArr [] ;
Boolean  booeanArr [][] ;
```

To declare  more readable array in java use following convention

String [][] myStringArray;

Answer (score 2):

This is an example that shows you when the `[]` position makes a difference.

```
Boolean[] arr, arr2[];
```

The `arr` is an array of `Boolean` whereas the `arr2` is an array of arrays of `Boolean`.